# do i need to call _gaq.push(['_trackPageView']) more than once on a page when using goog analytics asynchronous code?

Tags: google-analytics

i am using the vanilla ga asynchronous code thusly, right before end of `</head>`:

```
<script>
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
</head>
```

now, later in the middle of the page i call:

```
<script>
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
  1,
  'usertype',
  'anon',
  2
]);
</script>
```

the question is, do i need to make another call to _trackPageView?

that is, should i add another

`_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);`

...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you will need to make another call to `_trackPageView` in order to count the `_setCustomVar`.  However, this will count as 2 separate page views, which is going to inflate the # of page views for the page.  So you should instead move the `_setCustomVar` up to before `_trackPageView` is called.

Answer (score 1):

Calling two `_trackPageview`s **will** send the custom variable to GA, **however** this will cause a few negative consequences:

- Bounce rate will turn to 0%
- pages per visit will increase by 1

To get around this you can:

- move the custom variable before the initial `_trackPageview`, **or**:
- trigger some other call to GA, such as an Event, User Timing Event, Social Event (or last resort, `_trackPageview,'fake page name'`, and filter the 'fake page name' out of all reporting)